# DTO not working for microservice, but working for apis directly

Tags: microservices, nestjs, class-validator

I am developing apis & microservices in nestJS,
this is my controller function

```
    @Post()
    @MessagePattern({ service: TRANSACTION_SERVICE, msg: 'create' })
    create( @Body() createTransactionDto: TransactionDto_create ) : Promise<Transaction>{
        return this.transactionsService.create(createTransactionDto)
    }
```

when i call post api, dto validation works fine, but when i call this using microservice validation does not work and it passes to service without rejecting with error.
here is my DTO

```
import { IsEmail, IsNotEmpty, IsString } from 'class-validator';
export class TransactionDto_create{
    @IsNotEmpty()
    action: string;

    // @IsString()
    readonly rec_id : string;

    @IsNotEmpty()
    readonly data : Object;

    extras : Object;
    // readonly extras2 : Object;
}
```

when i call api without action parameter it shows error action required but when i call this from microservice using

> const pattern = { service: TRANSACTION_SERVICE, msg: 'create' };
>       const data = {id: '5d1de5d787db5151903c80b9', extras:{'asdf':'dsf'}};
>
> ```
> return this.client.send<number>(pattern, data)
> ```
>
> it does not throw error and goes to service.
>   I have added globalpipe validation also.

```
app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe({
    disableErrorMessages: false,  // set true to hide detailed error message
    whitelist: false,  // set true to strip params which are not in DTO
    transform: false // set true if you want DTO to convert params to DTO class by default its false
  }));
```

how will it work for both api & microservice, because i need all at one place and with same functionality so that as per clients it can be called.

Answer (score 9):

ValidationPipe throws HTTP BadRequestException, where as the proxy client expects RpcException.

```
@Catch(HttpException)
export class RpcValidationFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
    catch(exception: HttpException, host: ArgumentsHost) {
        return new RpcException(exception.getResponse())
    }
}
```

```
@UseFilters(new RpcValidationFilter())
@MessagePattern('validate')
async validate(
    @Payload(new ValidationPipe({ whitelist: true })) payload: SomeDTO,
) {
    // payload validates to SomeDto 
    . . .
}
```

Comment: rpc can pass the response correctly in the body but the http status code is not updated

Answer (score 3):

As I understood, useGlobalPipes is working fine for api but not for microservice.
Reason behind this, nest microservice is a hybrid application and it has some restrictions. Please refer below para.

> By default a hybrid application will not inherit global pipes, interceptors, guards and filters configured for the main (HTTP-based) application. To inherit these configuration properties from the main application, set the inheritAppConfig property in the second argument (an optional options object) of the connectMicroservice() call.

Please refer this [Nest Official Document](https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/hybrid-application#sharing-configuration)

So, you need to add *inheritAppConfig* option in connectMicroservice() method.

```
const microservice = app.connectMicroservice(
  {
    transport: Transport.TCP,
  },
  { inheritAppConfig: true },
);
```

It worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

I'm going out on a limb and assuming in you `main.ts` you have the line `app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());`. [From the documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/pipes#class-validator)

> In the case of **hybrid apps** the `useGlobalPipes()` method doesn't set up pipes for gateways and micro services. For "standard" (non-hybrid) microservice apps, `useGlobalPipes()` does mount pipes globally.

You could instead bind the pipe globally from the `AppModule`, or you could use the `@UsePipes()` decorator on each route that will be needing validation via the `ValidationPipe`

[More info on binding pipes here](https://docs.nestjs.com/pipes#binding-pipes)

Comment: I tried this, but issue is, even if validation works, it only gives internal service error is response to microservice, it shows complete error in the service but on service from which i am calling, there it only shows internal server error response.
Like I call function of srevice A from Service B, on Service A it shows complete error like validation failed but on service B it shows only internal server error. I need complete error there too so that on that service client should now what was the error.

Comment: That sounds like an issue of propagating the error and returning, in your case, from Service A to Service B. I'd suggest setting up some `Filters` to help with this functionality

Comment: i solved it, issue was, validation pipe throws Exception object, which works fine when using api directly, but microservice client is built in such a way that it only accepts whole error object if its type is RpcException, i just added custom validation pipe which extends to validation Pipe, and change exceptino to RpcException now its working.

Comment: @MuhammadAadilBanaras method will work but it will cost all the class-validator features. I recommend custom filters to catch HttpException and throw the RpcException.